# How should I mount a host httpd.conf file into an Apache httpd Docker container?

Tags: docker, apache, httpd.conf

I'm spinning up a docker container using:

```
docker run -d \
    --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
    --name=apache \
    --restart always \
    -e PUID=1000 \
    -e PGID=1000 \
    -e TZ=Europe/London \
    -p 80:80 \
    -v /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Container/apache/config/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf \
    -v /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Container/apache/config/httpd-vhosts.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf \
    httpd:latest
```

Unfortunately, the `httpd.conf` file within the container does **not** match the local file in the host. Interestingly, the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file within the container matches the local file in the host.

Comment: That `docker run` command seems okay, and matches the [`httpd` image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd).  When you say "it does not match", what do you actually see?  Are you using the Docker engine directly on a native Linux system, or something else?

Comment: I see the "original" httpd.conf file, i.e. the one which comes by default with the httpd:latest build.

Answer (score 0):

Build your own image based on httpd:latest as it is described [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)

```
FROM httpd:latest
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Assuming you do not care about frequent configuration changes, which requires restarting Apache anyway, for performance reasons, it is better to have this copied directly to the image.

Comment: Can do and thanks for the tip. Would you know why though it does not replace that specific file?

Comment: Doesn't it replace with both COPY and mount? What is your host OS? You can try set USER before COPY or set owner during COPY with flag `--chown=www`

Comment: This is running on a QNAP NAS. The COPY isn't actually working for both files with ```...Container/apache/config/httpd-vhosts.conf: file does not exist```. Clearly something else as that file exists and it's actually mounted when doing the docker run,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same issue, I've solved this by placing the whole `conf` directory in the host and mapping it in the docker run with:

```
-v /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Container/apache/conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf
```

First I had to run the container and copy (docker cp) container_id:/usr/local/apache2/conf into the host.

No problems since then.